# Big-O of a function with pointer that increments twice in one iteration

Tags: algorithm, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, big-o

So consider the problem where the midpoint of a linked list has to be found.
One solution is to traverse through the list, find its length and then find the middle element. 
Another solution is having a fast pointer and a slow pointer.
I intuitively feel that the second method has a O(n/2) but isn't the fast pointer accessing its next node before going to the next->next node?

What is the O() of these two methods? Is there a difference between Big-O and run-time?

Comment: What is a fast pointer?

Comment: O(n/2) is still O(n). Constant multipliers don't affect Big-O complexity.

Comment: Btw o(n/2) should be o(n)

Answer (score 0):

To compare the algorithms, it helps to be specific about what we're comparing. Here's implementations of the two algorithms, specifically written to make it easy to count instructions.

The first looks like this:

```
length := 0
node := first
repeat {
    if node == null { break }
    node = node->next
    length += 1
}
middle := first
length = (length - 1) / 2
repeat {
    if length == 0 { break }
    middle = middle->next
    length -= 1
}
```

The second looks like this:

```
fast := first
slow := first
repeat {
    if fast == null { break }
    fast = fast->next
    if fast == null { break }
    fast = fast->next
    slow = slow->next
}
```

Both algorithms perform exactly the same number of null checks, and exactly the same number of `->next` indirections.

The first algorithm does `N + 2 + (N/2)*2` (approximately `2N`) arithmetic operations on `length`.

The difference in runtime of the two algorithms is likely tiny. Although the first algorithm does the additional integer operations, on a modern machine the memory accesses needed for `->next` dominate, and these are the same in both implementations.

The run-time complexities are identical. The first does an additional O(N) integer operations, but both are O(N) overall.

Answer (score -2):

worst case time complexity of both these methods is O(n). The only difference is in case of huge lists, the first algorithm will need 2 passes(first to find the length of the LinkedList and 2nd pass to find the middle element). To formally express the time complexity :

> i.e Time Complexity = O(n) + O(n/2) ~= O(n)

The 2nd algorithm is a single pass algorithm and you can find middle element after the first pass. Your intuition feeling that second algorithm has O(n/2) is not true. Although your Fast pointer only visits n/2 elements but it is still linear function of the input length. O(n/2) ~= O(n)

```
Time complexity = O(n).
```

For larger lists, avoiding 2nd pass will result in faster execution. But the whole idea of Big O notation is to express the time complexity as a growth function of input size and ignore the other details.